# Why can I assign incompatible lambda to Action?

Tags: c#, lambda, action

I'm confused as to why this works:

```
Action myAction1 = () => myIntFunc(); 
...
private Int32 myIntFunc() {
    return(4);
    }
```

I would expect the compiler to not allow this because an Action represents functions that do not return parameters, yet myIntFunc clearly returns a parameter.

As further evidence, note that this does not work:

```
Action myAction2 = myIntFunc;
```

So it's like the lambda syntax is letting me get away with something I shouldn't be able to get away with. I'm guessing I'm overlooking something to do with how Actions and lambdas work together...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [C# language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx), paragraph 6.5, one of the bullets says: *If D has a void return type and the body of F is an expression, when each parameter of F is given the type of the corresponding parameter in D, the body of F is a valid expression (wrt §7) that would be permitted as a statement-expression (§8.6).*

So it's OK to throw away the return value in that case.

For a method group conversion, see paragraph 6.6 instead. Then the method must be compatible **including** the return type.

So there's a difference between anonymous method (lambda) and normal (named) method (or method group).

Answer (score 2):

I think its the same than when you do this:

```
myIntFunc();
```

Ignoring the result of the method.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is explicitly allowed. Per the MSDN documentation on the [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) delegate (emphasis added):

> The encapsulated method must have no parameters and no return value. (In C#, the method must return void. […] **It can also be a method that returns a value that is ignored.**)